# Android Studio 0.4 & Butter Knife

Tags: java, android, annotations, android-studio

I'm unable to get Android Studio 0.4 (gradle project) & Jake Wharton's [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to play well together. The reference to the view (ViewPager that's supposed to get injected is always null.

I've tried enabling annotation processing (Settings -> Compilers -> Annotation Processors -> Enable annotation processing) and cleaning, but it still doesn't work.

**Edit**: 
In case it's of relevance, the view I'm trying to inject is a `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`

**Edit 2:**
Complete solution:

```
buildScript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.jimdo.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.2-SNAPSHOT'
    } }

apply plugin: 'apt'

android {       
    butterknifeVersion = '4.0.1'
    dependencies {
        apt "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${butterknifeVersion}"
        compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${butterknifeVersion}"
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question if your project is Gradle-based, but if it is, then that settings page isn't going to help. You can start here and see if that takes you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742900/how-do-i-get-dagger-and-butterknife-working-with-gradle

Comment: @ScottBarta updated my question to clarify that it is a gradle project. Will take a look at that link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try run the annotation processing tool before the compile

```
dependency {
     apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:(insert latest version)'
     compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:(insert latest version)'
}
```

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20742913/1473536

Comment: After taking a 2nd look, I realized I missed the dependency (apt) higher up the chain. Thanks!