# NoClassDefFoundError for retrofit.RestAdapter$Builder

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit

I'm using Android Studio and I would like to use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), a rest client for Android and Java.

I added retrofit in dependencies of my `build.gradle` file. So, I can use it on my project but when I would like to execute it, I have a `NoClassDefFoundError` for `retrofit.RestAdapter$Builder` inner class.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.3.0'
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit for solution :**

1. Updates your Android Studio to 4.0+
2. Enables annotations in `Preferences > Compiler > Annotation Processors > Enable Annotation processing`.

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit requires annotation processing. Try

```
   dependencies {
     apt 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.3.0'
     compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.3.0'
   }
```

Check out this post for a similar situation: [Android Studio 0.4 & Butter Knife](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030078/android-studio-0-4-butter-knife)

Comment: Retrofit does not require annotation processing.