# Error using Retrofit Rest Adapter : NoClassDefFoundError: Retrofit.Restadapter$Builder

Tags: java, android, retrofit

My application always crashes when i instantiate the RestAdapter

```
private void submitForm(SignupForm form){
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
                .build();
        SignUpApi signUpApi = adapter.create(SignUpApi.class);
    signUpApi.sendStudentForm(form);
}
```

i also included retrofit.jar file and Gson.jar file.
There is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190155/noclassdeffounderror-for-retrofit-restadapterbuilder) but i dont use gradle.

Stack trace:

> 02-06 13:04:13.021: D/mali_winsys(22638): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
>
> 02-06 13:04:16.876: E/dalvikvm(22638): Could not find class 'retrofit.RestAdapter$Builder', referenced from method com.example.squiz.SignupActivity.submitForm
>
> 02-06 13:04:16.876: W/dalvikvm(22638): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 55 (Lretrofit/RestAdapter$Builder;) in Lcom/example/squiz/SignupActivity;
>
> 02-06 13:04:16.876: D/dalvikvm(22638): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
>
> 02-06 13:04:16.881: D/dalvikvm(22638): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x004c at 0x02 in Lcom/example/squiz/SignupActivity;.submitForm
>
> 02-06 13:04:16.881: W/ApplicationPackageManager(22638): getCSCPackageItemText()
>
> 02-06 13:04:16.956: D/mali_winsys(22638): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: D/AndroidRuntime(22638): Shutting down VM
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: W/dalvikvm(22638): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416cfc08)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638): Process: com.example.squiz, PID: 22638
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.RestAdapter$Builder
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at com.example.squiz.SignupActivity.submitForm(SignupActivity.java:66)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at com.example.squiz.SignupActivity.access$5(SignupActivity.java:65)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at com.example.squiz.SignupActivity$1.onClick(SignupActivity.java:55)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4630)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19339)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
>
> 02-06 13:04:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(22638):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 02-06 13:04:19.896: I/Process(22638): Sending signal. PID: 22638 SIG: 9
>
> 02-06 13:04:20.181: W/ApplicationPackageManager(25502): getCSCPackageItemText()
>
> 02-06 13:04:20.181: I/PersonaManager(25502): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
>
> 02-06 13:04:20.226: D/dalvikvm(25502): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 51K, 7% free 16826K/18032K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
>
> 02-06 13:04:20.256: I/dalvikvm-heap(25502): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.879MB for 7680016-byte allocation
>
> 02-06 13:04:20.266: D/dalvikvm(25502): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 24326K/25536K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
>
> 02-06 13:04:20.351: I/(25502): PLATFORM VERSION : JB-MR-2
>
> 02-06 13:04:20.366: D/mali_winsys(25502): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
>
> 02-06 13:04:20.391: D/OpenGLRenderer(25502): Enabling debug mode 0

Comment: Post the entire stack trace.

Comment: i also face same problem

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue by add

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/pom.xml'
}
```

in gradle.

My network lib

```
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0'
```