# Butter Knife won't inject

Tags: butterknife

I'm trying to use [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) at Android Studio these days, yet it fails me with some odd problems. I used to try Butter Knife at eclipse, and it worked fine. I don't know if I configured something wrong at Android Studio.

I followed instructions at Jake Wharton's [website](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), yet it's still not working. At first, It could be compiled and installed, but after `Butterknife.inject(this)`, the view would still be null, and it threw a null pointer error. Then I googled how to configure Butterknife at Android Studio, and followed [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030078/android-studio-0-4-butter-knife) at stackoverflow, it could not pass compilation then.

Then I reverted to my first version of configuration, it also began to fail compilation. Here's the message:

`Error:(14, 12): @InjectView-annotated class incorrectly in Android framework package. (android.rocky.butterknife_test.MyActivity)`

and

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
 Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`

---

This is my configuration of `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.rocky.butterknife_test"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            runProguard false
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.2'
}
```

This is my configuration of `build.gradle` at root:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

This is my Java code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  @InjectView(R.id.greeting)
  TextView greetingTextView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    greetingTextView.setText("butter knife!");
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

BTW, my android studio version is 0.8.2. If you think the snippets I paste are all fine, tell me to paste other snippets. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception says it all:

> @InjectView-annotated class incorrectly in Android framework package. (android.rocky.butterknife_test.MyActivity)

Your class is in the Android framework package, `android.*`. Applications should not use the `android.*` or `java.*` packages for their code. ButterKnife will eagerly reject these packages.

Comment: I don't understand what to do? please help.