# ButterKnife first use error

Tags: android, butterknife

after my suffering from `findViewById` I decided to use `ButterKnife` 
but nice bug told me that you will never ues ButterKnife 
here is the error

> @InjectView-annotated class incorrectly in Android framework package.

why? where is my mistake? is `gradle dependency` wrong?

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152401/butter-knife-wont-inject) but it didn't help me

gradle file (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
}
```

the error in this line

```
@BindView(R.id.button_birth_date)
private Button buttonBirthDate;
```

and other member variables(views) that uses  @BindView

Comment: what is your application package name ?

Comment: add your build.gradle too

Comment: `package="android.alcode.com.material"`  from `manifest file`

Comment: How about you show us the code that gives this error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By Jake Wharton,
The exception says it all:

```
@InjectView-annotated class incorrectly in Android framework package.
```

Your class is in the Android framework package, android.*. Applications should not use the android.* or java.* packages for their code. ButterKnife will eagerly reject these packages.

Change your package name. **android.alcode.com.material**  to **something.alcode.com.material**

Answer (score 2):

your package name mustn't contain `android` word on it

> so make sure that `your application package` name doesn't contain
>   `android word` on it

Answer (score 0):

If you use the last Butterknife you do use Butterknife.bind(this) not Butterknife.inject(this), for view use @Bind(R.id.idview) not @InjectView(R.id.idview).
See [documentation](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Edit: Change your package name, you can't'use android.* or java.*, Jake Wharton answer solution